# Change Dialog Window Width in Lightswitch HTML Client

Tags: jquery, html, css, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

In the MS Lightswitch HTML Client, when a dialog menu option has too many characters for the dialog window's length, the text is truncated and the missing characters replaced with (...).

Is there anyway to add a scroll bar or alter the text size when this occurs? I havent found a way to address this single element using JQuery either.

[image: Problem Image]
[image: Visual Studio View]

Comment: not a way to extend the width of the details picker, but if you change the type from text to paragraph, this will display all of the information below. hope that helps. if you want to format better also, you can add a label to explain what the user is seeing

Comment: How do you change a details picker from text to paragraph? I can't seem to find the option on the add/edit screen.

Answer (score 1):

On the screen.lsml, for example AddEditSite, you can change it on here, see screen shot below. This should format the text in terms of multi-line, so all the data can be seen

[image]

the next image shows the properties window which will let you add a label (this appears when the field is highlighted with a small blue line around it, such as Site Email in my example. Normally in your type of window you would set the label to top or left.

[image]

Please see the adjustment below for the details picker. If you set this to Row, within the details picker, and then within that group, click on your label, this will let you change it to a paragraph like shown above.

[image]

if you require additional information let me know.

Comment: Because I'm using a FK for the details picker, I don't have this option. I've attached a screenshot to my question of the options I have in VS.

Comment: hopefully the adjustment to the answer above helps. In doing this, you can add in more than 1 property, for example, a part and its description.